# if $\pi_1(G)$ is trivial, how to prove $ \pi_1(G/H)=\pi_0(H)/\pi_0(G) $?

Tags: algebraic-topology, topological-groups

Let $G$ be a topological group, $H$ be its normal subgroup of $G$, and $G/H$ be the quotient space induced by the natural map.(We know that $G/H$ is again a topological group)

If $\pi_1(G)$ is trivial, how to prove $ \pi_1(G/H)=\pi_0(H)/\pi_0(G) $?
The author of this article use this fact directly in the page 5, but I want to know the proof of it.

http://ocw.u-tokyo.ac.jp/lecture_files/sci_03/11/notes/en/ooguri11.pdf

Plus: Can anybody show me a book of an article on the introduction to the fundamental group of topological group? It is really hard for me to find one.

Comment: What is the context for $G$ and $H$?

Comment: The quotient map is a fibration so you can use the long exact sequence in homotopy groups.

Comment: I like Helgason's book on differential geometry and Lie groups.

Comment: Try to figure out what new loops $G/H$ gets that $G$ didn't have (for simplicity, let $G$ be connected and $H$ a discrete set of points at first). Then see what they correspond to in $G$ to figure out why they're not nullhomotopic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the article you linked there is a proof at the bottom of the page (After “To prove these relations...”), but it's obfuscated by a typo.

Whenever $F\stackrel{i}{\rightarrow} E \stackrel{p}{\rightarrow} B$ is a [fibration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibration), there is a [long exact sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_sequence) in homotopy, moving downward by degree.  At the end of the sequence you have
$$\pi_1(G) \longrightarrow \pi_1(G/H) \stackrel{\beta}{\longrightarrow} \pi_0(H) \stackrel{i_*}{\longrightarrow} \pi_0(G) \stackrel{p_*}{\longrightarrow} \pi_0(G/H) \longrightarrow 0
$$
This is the line marked (2) in the link, but $\pi_0(H)$ is written as $\pi_0(G)$.

The assumption is that $\pi_1(G)$ is trivial, so $\beta$ is an injection.  This means that $\pi_1(G/H)$ is isomorphic to the image of $\beta$.  Since the sequence is exact, the image of $\beta$ is equal to the kernel of $i_*$.  And the kernel of $i_*$ is the set of components of $H$ that are contained in the identity component of $G$.  That is, $\pi_0(H)/\pi_0(G)$.

Comment: Looks like we were both writing answers 21 hours after the question was posted :P Sorry that they're so similar.

Comment: Wow, we even chose some of the same notation.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Matthew Leingang gave the answer in a comment but I'll flesh it out a little. The quotient map $q\colon G\to G/H$ is a fibration with fiber topologically isomorphic to $H$, and so we get a long exact sequence in homotopy groups
$$\cdots \to \pi_{k+1}(G) \to \pi_{k+1}(G/H) \stackrel{\delta_k}{\to} \pi_k(H) \stackrel{i_*}{\to} \pi_k(G) \to \pi_k(G/H) \to\cdots.$$
Using the fact that $\pi_1(G)=0$ this gives a short exact sequence at $k=0$ which looks like $$0 \to \pi_1(G/H) \stackrel{\delta_0}{\to} \pi_0(H) \stackrel{i_*}{\to} \pi_0(G) \to \pi_0(G/H)$$ where we see that $\delta_0$ is an injection by exactness, so $\pi_1(G/H)$ is embedded as a subgroup into $\pi_0(H)$. The image of $\delta_0$ is equal to the kernel of $i_*$ by exactness, so $\ker i_* \cong \pi_1(G/H)$. But, we also know that the kernal of $i_*$ is the set of path components of $H$ which are included into the path component containing the identity element of $G$, which is precisely $\pi_0(H)/\pi_0(G)$.

Comment: Something that might be worth noting is that $\pi_0$ is not normally a group, so the long exact sequence is usually just a sequence of sets at the $\pi_0$ level. However, $\pi_0$ of a topological group is a group, and one needs to then observe that the exactness is compatible with this group structure.

Comment: Yes, and even if the spaces being considered aren't $H$-spaces/topological groups, the 'exactness' of the sequence can still be meaningful if we regard the 'kernel' of a map between pointed sets as the set of elements which are mapped to the basepoint in the codomain (In this case the set of path components in $H$ which are mapped to the basepoint of the set of path components of $G$, which is the the path component containing the basepoint/identity of $G$).

Comment: If $G_0$ is the identity component of $G$, is $\pi_0(G) \cong G/G_0$?  Seems reasonable but wasn't sure.